# Umbraco MVC-like routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco7

I currently have a controller that needs to process parameters passed to umbraco's actions. What I did was adding a controller for my `Document Type`:

```
public class MyDocumentTypeController : RenderMvcController
{
    public ActionResult SignUp(RenderModel model, [Bind(Prefix="rc")] string myArgument = null)
    {
        // some logic
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Now I'm able to pass arguments to that action. Assuming my content of `MyDocumentType` is available under address `http://mypage/mydocumenttype`, so I can pass arguments to my action like this: `http://mypage/mydocumenttype/signup?rc=1234ef`. What I dislike is:

- I cannot put constraints on the argument
- I can't make use of MVC-like paths, like: `http://mypage/mydocumenttype/signup/1234ef`

To achieve it I added routing:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapUmbracoRoute(
        "MyDocumentType",
        "MyDocumentType/{action}/{myArgument}",
        new { controller = "MyDocumentType", action = "Index", myArgument = UrlParameter.Optional },
        /* WHAT GOES HERE? */,
        new { myArgument = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}$" });
}
```

However, if I create plain-old-vanila MVC routing I loose Umbraco's context which I need. If I use `MapUmbracoRoute` I don't know what `IRouteHandler` should be passed. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered using `new UmbracoVirtualNodeByIdRouteHandler(1234))`? The drawback is that this will redirect to a specific page, in this example the node with id 1234, but you can create your own route handler if you need more control.

Comment: Yes, I have. In that case on each request I'll need to find proper node (always the same) and it sucks :/

Comment: In that case, the following link could help you create your own handler implementation: http://jamessouth.me/archive/fun-with-umbracovirtualnoderoutehandler/